# Hadoop userlogs "not found" via a browser

Tags: browser, hadoop, web, logging

I have problem viewing my hadoop userlogs files via web interface. The same log files are visible via terminal. What do you think the reason is? Thank you
[image: Hadoop User Logs are not accessible via a browser]